# 'var' is an invalid keyword argument for this function? (Tkinter and Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having trouble updating a label in tkinter.  I looked at all the other questions i could find on this error but none were really relevant to my situation.  Anyway, here is my code:

```
var = 100

v = StringVar()
v.set(str(var))
varLabel=Label(app, textvariable=v).grid(row=0)

#this is where i update my label
#also, this is where i get the error
v.set(str(var = var - dictionary[number]))
```

The error says:

```
'var' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: `str` function in python doesn't have `var` keyword argument.

Comment: It looks like you're coming from a C-derived language (C++, Java, C#, D, whatever). Unlike those languages, assignment in Python is not an expression. You can't assign a value to a variable in the middle of a function call or a while condition or anywhere else; you can only do it as a statement on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to do too many things at once.

Try this

```
var = var - dictionary[number]
v.set(str(var))
```

OR

```
var = str(var - dictionary[number])
v.set(var)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that the `str()` callable does not take a `var` keyword argument. The syntax you used is normally used for keyword arguments.

Assign separately:

```
var = var - dictionary[number]
v.set(str(var))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

`v.set(str(var = var - dictionary[number]))`

I think you're expecting the interpreter to calculate `var - dictionary[number]`; assign that value into `var`; and then pass the value of `var` along to the `str()` function as the first argument.

The first part of that does actually work - the interpreter *does* calculate `var - dictionary[number]`. However, instead of putting that value into `var`, it passes that value along to the `str` function as an argument named `var`. Because the string function isn't expecting an argument named `var` you get the error you've seen.

Here's a quick iPython interpreter session showing this in action.

```
In [1]: def func1(var):
   ...:     print var
   ...:

In [2]: def func2(notvar):
   ...:     print notvar
   ...:

In [3]: var=12

In [4]: func1(var=var+3)
15

In [5]: func2(var=var+3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7e6ea7fc32e9> in <module>()
----> 1 func2(var=var+3)

TypeError: func2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'var'

In [6]:print var
12
```

You can see that func1, which does expect an argument named var, handles this fine. func2, which doesn't expect an argument called var, throws a TypeError about the unexpected keyword. The value of `var` is unchanged.